# in SQL if two tables both begin with same letter and you want to select columns from both tables. how do you distinguish the tables. thanks

Tags: sql

In SQL if two tables both begin with same letter (ie a table called Properties and another table called PropertySale) and you want to select columns from both tables, how do you distinguish the tables. Is the following code correct?

```
Select P.propertyaddress, P.propertydescription, PS.EstateAgent
FROM Property P, Propertysale PS
Where P.PropertyID = PS.PropertyID
AND P.City = 'London'
```

Comment: Table aliases are not limited to a single letter. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You code runs, but is not correct.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT P.propertyaddress, P.propertydescription, PS.EstateAgent
FROM Property P JOIN
     Propertysale PS 
     ON P.PropertyID = PS.PropertyID 
WHERE P.City = 'London';
```

Your choice of `P` and `PS` for table aliases is a very good choice.  Those are reasonable abbreviations for the table names, so they are easy to follow through the logic of the query.